# Django, Detecting if variable is a number

Tags: python, django, string, integer

In a function in Django, the user can send me a number or a string, and I want to know if I received a number or a String (Tip: The number will always be an integer between 1-6)

I want to know if it's possible to detect this and how (with an example), as the number or string I'm getting will tell me what to do next.

Comment: **How** is the number sent? In a request?

Comment: Like this: def make_choice(request, option):

Comment: Then `option` is **always** a string.

Comment: So, trying to convert it into an integer like int(option) will only work if it's a number originally. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to convert the string to a number using `int()`, catching the exception:

```
def isNum(data):
    try:
        int(data)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

This returns `True` only if the string can be converted to an integer number.

Comment: @Christian: That is what exceptions are *for*. Not just to detect coding errors. And no, this is not slow, this is actually faster than the alternatives, which is to use a regular expression or a series of string method tests.

Comment: @Christian: Can you show me anything other than "It's probably slow"? Because that's not much of an argument; do you have *proof*?

Answer (score 7):

What about: `if isinstance(data, int):`

Comment: For folks who are looking to identify numbers which could be represented as strings: please note that this won't work for you. `isinstance('7', int)` will return `False`

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your number will still be encased in a string, ie. "1" or "4" or "6" - if that's the case, then there are several ways to do it; you could use a regex to check whether it is a number or not, or you could knock up a function that would look something like this

```
def isNumber(your_input_string):
    return len(your_input_string) == 1 and your_input_string in "123456"
```

Since the number will always be between 1 and 6, it can only be a string of length 1, and it must be contained in the string '123456', since... well, those are the allowed numbers.

**EDIT**:

As pointed by Martijn Pieters in the comments below, that is a roundabout way of doing it; an easier solution would be just to check whether the string is between '1' or '6'.

```
def isNumber(your_input_string):
    return len(your_input_string) == 1 and '1' <= your_input_string <= '6'
```

Comment: You can simply write that as `return len(your_input_string) == 1 and your_input_string in "123456"` and there are no `true` and `false` in python

Comment: This is rather... round-about. `return len(your_input_string) == 1 and '1' <= your_input_string <= '6'` would do the same, but faster.

Comment: - I can't believe I overlooked the fact that I'm basically just returning a boolean expression. That's a bit embarassing. 

It's been a while since I last programmed anything in python, so I wasn't even sure if my syntax was correct. I didn't even remember that you could do comparisons with <= on strings - that's brilliantly elegant solution.

Comment: You do need to test for the length here; `'1' <= '16' <= '6'` is `True` as well, due to lexicographic ordering.